# Table-cell <a> element different height in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-tables

I'm pretty baffled about this element displaying differently in Chrome than in Safari and Firefox.

I have an `<a>` that is supposed to match the height of its parent `<div>`. It does in Safari and Firefox, but not Chrome. I can't set the height manually, because the same code is used for several differently-sized items on the page.

The apparently relevant styles for the `<a>` element are:

```
display: table-cell;
width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;
```

The apparently relevant styles for the `<div>` element are:

```
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

However, it's quite possible that the problem is coming from some other code, and I don't know enough to see it.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `height:100%`, and removing `position:relative`.

Comment: You should do the basic debugging, isolating the problem so that you can include a minimal example that actually reproduces the issue. A request to do the debugging for you, on a live site, is not the kind of questions that SO is for. The code included now does not even contain anything trying to set the height (which is the issue), and it contains apparently irrelevant parts like transition settings.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for setting me on course. I updated my question above. Is it better? (Part of the problem is that I'm not even quite sure where the problem is occurring and don't want to accidentally exclude relevant code.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. When I do that, the `<a>` element is the right height, but the items inside it aren't vertically centered anymore. So either that's the "wrong fix," so to speak, or it required additional changes to work. I'm open to ideas!

Comment: @CBroe I removed some `<span>` elements the `<a>` element was containing and now everything is vertically centering correctly. Can I give you points for a comment?

Comment: I added an answer, with a little more explanation.

Comment: Thanks! Not enough reputation to upvote your answer, but I marked it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The apparently relevant styles for the  element are: display:
>   table-cell; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle; position: relative;
>
> The apparently relevant styles for the  element are: display:
>   table; width: 100%; height: 100%;

Try adding `height:100%`, and removing `position:relative` for the links.

`height:100%`, so that the `a` elements take the same height as specified for their parent (not necessarily the case for table cells depending on browser), and removing `position:relative`, because relative positioning of `table-cell` elements is somewhat problematic, with the result being undefined in the CSS 2.1 specification, and some browser vendors seemingly having different opinions on the clarification of that with CSS 3, or there simply still being bugs in implementing CSS 3 in that regard.